# view data from 2 different column using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, view

```
SELECT dun_nama, mohonID, 
(CASE WHEN b_telMobile IS NOT NULL AND b_telMobile!="" AND b_telMobile!="-" then b_telMobile
ELSE CASE WHEN  i_telMobile IS NOT NULL AND i_telMobile!="" AND i_telMobile!="-" then i_telMobile ELSE 0 end ) AS PENJAGA
FROM mohon 
LEFT JOIN log_cetakan_penyata
on mohon.noMyKid=log_cetakan_penyata.no_mykid
WHERE 
mohon.dun_nama = 'N41' 
AND(
(
status_bayar =  ''
OR status_bayar =  'Belum'
OR status_bayar =  'Sudah'
)
AND status_semak =  '1'
AND (
status_terima =  ''
OR status_terima =  'Terima'
)
AND status_mohon =  'Layak'
AND status_proses =  'diproses')
AND log_cetakan_penyata.tarikh_serah IS NULL
```

this is my sql query.what i want to try is to view data from table using case when. if B_telmobile not have data then it will view i_telMobile data. but i got an systax error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ELSE condition between two CASEs.

This is the syntax.

```
CASE
    WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
    [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```